# Why printf prints same string when function called back to back inside same statement

Tags: arrays, c, function, printf

In the below snippet, printf( ) prints same string even though the char array has been memset to 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char ip_addr[20];
char *ip_print(char *in)
{
    memset(ip_addr,0,20);
    strcpy(ip_addr,in);
    return ip_addr;
}
int main()
{
    printf("Ip addresses %s - %s",ip_print("226.0.0.1"),ip_print("10.1.1.1"));
    return 0;
}
```

output-
Ip addresses 226.0.0.1 - 226.0.0.1

Expected output-
Ip addresses 226.0.0.1 - 10.1.1.1

Comment: `ip_addr` is  a global variable, you pass a pointer to it twice to `printf` so the last assigned valued is used  twice by `printf`.

Comment: Basic debugging technique: add printf statements to your ip_print function, print out the in parameter and the return value. Then you will realize what is going on.

Comment: I see..thank you very much..appreciate your reply :)

Answer (score 0):

As @Pablo said above `ip_print()` updates a global variable and returns the (same) address twice. The order of evaluation of arguments, however, is unspecified so the result is undefined behavior (it may print either address twice).